# How to let the message pop-up "not executed" within a certain period of time?

Tags: java, android, delay

I want the *message text* of the program to be executed after a certain period of time.
For example, when `Managed roaming (sub1) Network with Limited Service found. Do you want to change Network Settings?` is displayed. I hope it will appear again after **at least** 1 hour.

I know the `schedule(task, delay)`, but it will execute after `&delay` time.
And I don't want to keep the timer running in the background, which will increase the burden on the CPU.

I really can’t think of a way to solve this problem, so I would like to ask someone who has had a similar experience to share with me.

(I'm really sorry if my English makes your reading painful...)

Comment: This may be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375968/android-execute-a-function-after-1-hour

Comment: This seems to help me, I will try it. Thank you.